# why does my query return nothing (marketing data in SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run a Google BQ query which returns how many people converted and did not convert against a health marketing campaign but it returns nothing

```
ble that has a list of patient ids with a column of their times and whether they converted or not. I thought I cracked where I'm I going wrong?
```

here is some example data
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious problem is:

```
 TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_time) BETWEEN timestamp_micros(2017-01-01) AND timestamp_micros(2017-12-26)
```

I speculate that you want:

```
TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_time) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01') AND TIMESTAMP('2017-12-26')
```

The expression `2017-01-01` evaluates to `2015` and that is not a very interesting number of microseconds, in general.

Comment: I get this error: No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP for argument types: INT64. Supported signatures: TIMESTAMP(STRING, [STRING]); TIMESTAMP(DATE, [STRING]) [at 6:21]

Comment: @stacker . . . Nothing in my code would generate that error, because the functions all have only one argument.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with looking at your WHERE statements which need quotes around dates and strings, etc. E.g.

```
activity_id IN ("first_campaign")
```

You also need to look at your data quality, e.g. "first_campain" missing the "g".